# Assumptions and trouble shooting for glmer (lme4) Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I've been trying to understand how to properly conduct a glmer model but I've come across so much contradictory information, I'm hoping someone could help me out.

1. What exactly are the assumptions of my glmer model?
2. What functions and packages do you recommend for testing them?
3. Can I still test the assumptions if my model used for assumption testing doesn't converge?
4. What can you do if the model doesn't converge? I'm grateful for any tips.

This is my model btw:

```
m.cluster1 <- glmer(formula = binary_var ~ continous_pred1 + binary_gender + binary_educationlevel2 + binary_educationlevel3 + binary_languagelevel2 + binary_languagelevel3 + binary_locationdensity2 + binary_locationdensity3 + binary_locationdensity4 + 
(1|state), weights=final_weights, data=data, family=binomial(link="logit"), control=glmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxfun=2000000000)))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is any extremely general question, but I'll give it a shot.

1. The assumptions combine the assumptions of generalized linear models and mixed models, among others:

   - the responses are *conditionally* independent (i.e., once you account for the fixed and random effects)
   - on the link (log-odds) scale, the response variable is a linear function of the fixed covariates
   - the random effects are Normally distributed with zero mean, random effects within a given term are independent and identically distributed (econometricians sometimes use additional assumptions about the independence of random and fixed effects)

Since your responses are binary, there are a couple of assumptions that are either not applicable or not testable (homoscedasticity/constant scale parameter/equidispersion; conformity of the conditional distribution of the response to the assumed distribution). (If you have repeated values of the covariates, it [is possible to test for overdispersion in a binary-response model](http://www.highstat.com/Books/BGS/GLMGLMM/pdfs/HILBE-Can_binary_logistic_models_be_overdispersed2Jul2013.pdf).)

2. While `performance::check_model()` does a good job providing graphical tests of GLMMs, binary responses are especially challenging, so I would recommend the `DHARMa` package as an alternative (especially `ss <- simulateResiduals(fitted_model); plot(ss)`). It would be worth reading through the whole [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) for the package.

Questions 3 and 4 are a little too general to answer here. The answer depends what kind of problem you experience (singular fits; "failed to converge with max|grad|"; "model is nearly unidentifiable"; etc.). General advice:

- read `help("troubleshooting", package = "lme4")` and `help("convergence", package = "lme4")`
- read the relevant sections of the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#troubleshooting)
- Google the warning messages and/or search here and on Stack Overflow
- the gold standard is usually to run `allFit()` and see if the results are sufficiently close across a range of optimizers
- double-check to make sure your model makes sense (if necessary, post a question here)
- simplify your model

---

PS a couple of notes about your model:

- it looks like you're constructing your own dummy variables from categorical predictors (`binary_*`). It's usually a better idea to use factor variables as predictors in the model, allowing R to construct dummies on the fly. (See the `contr_code_*` functions in the [faux package](https://debruine.github.io/faux/reference/index.html), currently only available from Github, for user-friendly ways to code contrasts.)
- using a `weights=` argument for binary data is unusual, and might not do what you think/you should be careful, e.g. see [here](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2020/08/04/weights-in-statistics/), [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/27276_8ff15b5bf845431fb1d89dea7c7aa424.html) (if you have survey data you may want to consider the [survey package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=survey) instead ...)